# python - build new path string from a splited one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I reading list of paths from XML, path contain irregular elemnts uses 
by a certian application that translate them internaly. 
the current path string is usless for me and I wish to normaliz them.

```
example: 
path = "%personal%\new_lcation\%vendorlibs%\generated"
# split this to a list
omponents = path.split(os.sep)
# replace elemnts 0,2
components[0]="c:\ProgramFiles"  
components[2]="somthing"
```

How do I join everythings now to standard path string?

thanks

Comment: You won't get what you expect because you're using plain string literals instead of "raw" string literals. For example, `"\n"` is the newline character. When working with paths on Windows, use raw strings, such as `r"%personal%\new_lcation\%vendorlibs%\generated"`.

Answer (score 3):

`os.path.join(*components)`. [`os.path.join` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).